# navbar dissapearing in preview and simulator when setting constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I'm currently following the udemy ios8/swift course and I'm completely stuck on the navigationbar part. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the fact that I'm on a higher version of Xcode, but can't seem to find the solution.

I have to set the constraints for the navbar on 0 on 3 sides so it will be centered and full width in both landscape and portrait mode. When I try to do this, I see a option thats not there on the course (Constrain to Margins). No matter how much I try to adjust the values, the navbar keeps disappearing or moving in the wrong direction. I tried unchecking the constrain to margins function and putting everything on 0, I tried 'resetting to suggested constraints' and lots of other options, but I can't seem to get my navbar look good in both landscape/portrait mode. So basically, what am I doing wrong or is there any other way to do this?

[image: The menu with 'Constrain to margins']
[image: My result most of the times after trying to get it right]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the three constraints you need to give the navigation bar a height.

Another solution is to add a navigation item to the view controller instead of a navigation bar. A navigation item will auto format a navigation bar at the top of the view.

Comment: Giving it a height isn't solving anything unfortunately. Adding a navigation item isn't working either, I can't seem to drag it into the viewcontroller when there's no navigation bar.

Comment: can you post some screenshots of the nav bar with constraints on the left, right and top and also a height

Comment: you can also try going to the attribute inspector of the scene and change the setting of Top Bar from Inferred to Opaque

Comment: I've fixed it using another method (see my answer) already, but I will try this as well to see if it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix it by manually setting the constraints to 0 in the Attribute inspector after Ctrl-dragging to create them first. Not sure if this is the ideal way, but it solved my problem for now.